# Robocopy: copy files preserving folder structure but adding a subfolder

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, directory, robocopy

I need to copy a folder which contains subfolders with files to a shared folder on another machine. During that the script should create a custom sub folder in each destination folder and place files there.

I hope this example clatifies the task:

1. **For the following source folder:**

   ```
   --Logs
   ----Application
   ------Service
   --------Log1.txt
   --------Log2.txt
   ------WebSite
   --------Log1.txt
   --------Log2.txt
   ```
2. **Destination folder should be created in the following way:**

   ```
   --Logs
   ----Application
   ------Service
   --------Machine1
   ----------Log1.txt
   ----------Log2.txt
   ------WebSite
   --------Machine1
   ----------Log1.txt
   ----------Log2.txt
   ```

As you see at the bottom level subfolders `Machine1` have been created.
Can you please provide an example of PowerShell script which performes that?

I investigated input parameters in ROBOCOPY command. It seems it doesn't allow to do that straightforward.

Also I know that I can symply iterate through all folder structure, create required sub folders and copy files to each subfolder. But it seems to be a too 'long' way. So I want to know if I'm missing anything. Maybe there is a better smart way to do that.

Comment: What version of Powershell are you running?

Comment: @mjolinor version 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `robocopy` for replicating the contents of the subfolders:

```
$srcBase = 'C:\some\Logs\Application'
$dstBase = 'D:\other\Logs\Application'

Get-ChildItem $srcBase | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % {
  $dst = "$dstBase\$($_.Name)\Machine1"

  & robocopy $_.FullName $dst /e
}
```

Comment: This one does not create the same folder structure in the destination. Actualy, it creates all subfolders directly inside the root folder. But I need a tree exactly like in source (see the example in my question)

Comment: @Egor4eg It worked just fine when I tested it. Note that you need to include the common parent folders (`Logs\Application`) in `$dstBase`. If it still doesn't work for you, please update your question with the code you're currently using.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It will work on my example. I forgot to mention that several 'Application' folders are possible. Sorry about that. In any case I wrote the script already and your comment was helpful. Marking it as an answer...