# Powershell Copy files and folders

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script which Zips up the previous months logs and names the zip file `FILENAME-YYYY-MM.zip`

This works

What I now want to do is copy these zip files off to a network share but keeping some of the folder structure. I currently a folder structure similar to the following;

```
C:\Folder1\
C:\Folder1\Folder2\
C:\Folder1\Folder3\
C:\Folder1\Folder4\Folder5\
```

There are .zip files in every folder below `c:\Folder1`
What I want is for the script to copy files from `c:\folder1` to `\\networkshare` but keeping the folder structure, so I should have 3 folders and another subfolder in `folder4`.

Currently I can only get it to copy the whole structure so I get `c:\folder1\...` in my `\\networkshare`

I keep running into issues such as the new folder structure doesn't exist, I can't use the `-recurse` switch within the `Get-ChildItem` command etc...

The script I have so far is;

```
#This returns the date and formats it for you set value after AddMonths to set archive date -1 = last month
$LastWriteMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3).ToString('MM')
#Set destination for Zip Files
$DestinationLoc = "\\networkshare\LogArchive\$env:computername"

#Source files
$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Sourcefiles\*.zip -Recurse | where-object {$_.lastwritetime.month -le $LastWriteMonth} 
Copy-Item $SourceFiles -Destination $DestinationLoc\ZipFiles\
Remove-Item $SourceFiles
```

Comment: Similar questions I've seen here have been answered by "Don't reinvent the wheel, just use robocopy," so that may be something to consider.

Comment: Yeah I think robocopy can resolve your problem. Look this question if help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606259/robocopy-copy-files-preserving-folder-structure-but-adding-a-subfolder

Comment: @TonyHinkle Using robocopy can produce problems if the robocopy log is to be parsed - I've got troubles with file encoding with that one, also robocopy puts ^H symbols if logged via `> file.log`. And, why not to program one's own solution on Powershell instead of relying on a third party software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, you just can't (easily) use a "pure PowerShell" solution. This is one of those times, and that's OK.

[`Robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx) will mirror directory structures, including any empty directories, and select your files (likely faster than a filter with `get-childitem` will). You can copy anything older than 90 days (about 3 months) like this:

```
robocopy C:\SourceFiles "\\networkshare\LogArchive\$($env:computername)\ZipFiles" /E /IS /MINAGE:90 *.zip
```

You can specify an actual date with `/MINAGE` too, if you have to be that precise.

Comment: Modified this a bit but thanks a bunch!
`$LastWriteMonth = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
$DestinationLoc = "\\networkshare\LogArchive\$env:computername\"
Robocopy C:\sourcefiles\ $DestinationLoc -IS -E -MINAGE:$LastWriteMonth *.zip`

Answer (score 1):

How about `Copy-Item "C:\SourceFiles\" -dest $DestinationLoc\ZipFiles -container -recurse`? I have tested this and have found that it copies the folder structure intact. If you only need `*.zip` files, you first get them, then for each you [call `Resolve-Path` with `-Relative` flag set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972589/get-relative-path-of-files-in-sub-folders-from-the-current-directory) and then add the resultant path into `Destination` parameter.

```
$oldloc=get-location
Set-Location "C:\SourceFiles\" # required for relative
$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Sourcefiles\*.zip -Recurse | where-object {$_.lastwritetime.month -le $LastWriteMonth}
$SourceFiles | % { 
    $p=Resolve-Path $_.fullname -relative
    copy-item $_ -destination "$DestinationLoc\ZipFiles\$p"
}
set-location $oldloc # return back
```