# Remove All Values In A String Before 7th backslash

Tags: powershell

I have a path inside a txt file that needs to be manipulated, something like:

C:\Jenkins\Automation\Blah\Foo\Bar\646433\Schema\test\473289_12321.ps1
C:\Jenkins\Automation\Blah\Foo\Bar\2112\Schema\QA\473289_123211.ps1

I want to replace everything before the 7th backslash and then replace it with C:\Question.  I was doing something similar in Powershell via:

```
(Get-Content $FullEnvSQLFilePath) |  #get the content
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace [Regex]::Escape($StringToReplace), "$StringReplaceValue"} | #look for the string and replace
```

This worked fine when I knew what the exact verbiage was to look for.  We now don't know that but we will want to remove everything before the 7th backslash and replace it with a value.  Reverse order works fine too.  I wasn't able to have much luck in Powershell via substring doing this.  Thanks.

Comment: Why restricting to 7th backslash? In case you would relocate your powershell script elsewhere you will have to use 6th backslash instead. I'd say look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972589/get-relative-path-of-files-in-sub-folders-from-the-current-directory) to get relative path to some root location, then you can use that path to form correct destination location like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573854/powershell-copy-files-and-folders/30574964#30574964).

Comment: Thanks Vesper, let me look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this `([^\\]*\\){7}` regex looks 7 times for a capture group ending on a backslash and replaces it.

**UPDATED**: `.:\\([^\\]*\\){6}` regex looks for strings that look like paths starting at any root drive `.:\` followed by 6 times a capture group ending on a backslash based on your comment

```powershell
$text = @"
C:\Jenkins\Automation\Blah\Foo\Bar\646433\Schema\test\473289_12321.ps1
C:\Jenkins\Automation\Blah\Foo\Bar\2112\Schema\QA\473289_123211.ps1
PRINT C:\Jenkins\Automation\Blah\Foo\Baz\2112\Schema\QA\473289_123212.ps1
C:\Jenkins\Automation\Blah\Foo\quux\2112\Schema\QA\473289_123213.ps1
"@
#depending on how you get the text (single string or array)
#$text.Split("`n") | % { $_ -Replace '.:\\([^\\]*\\){6}','C:\Example\' }
$text -Replace ".:\\([^\\`n]*\\){6}","C:\Example\"
```

**Result:**

```
C:\Example\Schema\test\473289_12321.ps1
C:\Example\Schema\QA\473289_123211.ps1
PRINT C:\Example\Schema\QA\473289_123212.ps1
C:\Example\Schema\QA\473289_123213.ps1
```

Comment: if you use `Get-Content` you may not need the split on newline and `For-EachObject` (`%`) script block and apply regex replace direct.

Comment: I excluded newline in capture group, so `%` is no longer needed

Comment: Thank you.  I have a problem where line 1 is PRINT c:\blah\blah\blah etc.

My process removes everything as soon as it finds 7 backslashes in a line.  Can I have it do the replace ONLY if either the line starts with :R or if it doesn't start with PRINT and it matches 7 backslashes?

Comment: Easy to change the regex from `([^\\`n]*\\){7}` to `.:\\([^\\`n]*\\){7}`, which is one of the reasons why it's better to go with a clear & easy to maintain regex. Even if you might sacrifice a tiny bit of performance

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
$text = 
'C:\Jenkins\Automation\Blah\Foo\Bar\646433\Schema\test\473289_12321.ps1',
'C:\Jenkins\Automation\Blah\Foo\Bar\2112\Schema\QA\473289_123211.ps1'

$text | foreach {'C:\Question\{0}' -f $_.split('\',8)[-1]}
C:\Question\Schema\test\473289_12321.ps1
C:\Question\Schema\QA\473289_123211.ps1
```

Comment: does this perform faster than a regex?

Comment: Haven't benchmarked it, but I'd expect it would.  Typically string method operations are faster than PS operators, and among those operators, the regex operations (-match, -replace, -split) tend to be the slowest.

Comment: Thank you.  I have a problem where line 1 is PRINT c:\blah\blah\blah etc.

My process removes everything as soon as it finds 7 backslashes in a line.  Can I have it do the replace ONLY if either the line starts with :R or if it doesn't start with PRINT and it matches 7 backslashes?

Comment: That's getting outside the range of the original question.  I'd post a new question for that.